# How to use FastLoadOptions ORDER in DataFlowTask OLE DB Destination?

Tags: ssis

I am using SSIS-Designer (stand-alone as part of DataTools or as extension to Visual Studio). I am within a Integration Services Project. In a DataFlowTask there is a Custom Property of the OLE DB Destination with the name "FastLoadOptions". If your input data is sorted (i.e. clustered index), you can use the parameter "ORDER". The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/ole-db-destination?view=sql-server-ver15) gives an syntax of

```
ORDER <column name> ASC|DESC
```

This syntax does not work. Execution would throgh an syntax error closed to .

If I use the undocumented syntax

```
ORDER (<column name> ASC|DESC)
```

there is no error message and everything seems to word. With very big data this option can speed up transfers significantly. The transfer should be minimal logged as well.

Does the option work with the undocumented syntax? Is it possible to check the intended impact of this option?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your second syntax using parentheses has to be correct, especially if multiple columns are being used.  Also, this syntax matches the bulk insert syntax: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

As far as minimal logging and performance is concerned, I would recommend checking this table and the section related to the ssis and the oledb destination: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd425070(v=sql.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#summarizing-minimal-logging-conditions

Some of the information in the article is dated, in newer versions, you no longer need to turn on trace flag 610.  However, here are some key considerations:

- If you are inserting into a heap, you must use TABLOCK.  NC indexes will be fully logged, if they exist.
- In the above case, concurrent loading is possible, so you can use the balanced data distributor component to distribute the load to multiple OLEDB destinations
- If you are loading a clustered index, use TABLOCK and ORDER.
- With SSIS, the batch size will either be the size of the buffer or the Maximum Insert Commit Size setting in the OLEDB destination.  This means that you might get minimal logging on the first batch but full logging after that, depending on the situation.  You can override this by setting the maximum insert commit size to 0
- To know if any of this is working, you have to benchmark it with different settings.  Make sure the load test is set up the way it would be in production.  If there are rows in the table in prod, make sure that is the same in your load test environment.